# RANDOM TEXT GENERATOR ERROR WITH JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

we're creating random text from an array of words. The idea is to shuffle, and mix the words to create new "random sentences". We've almost it, the point is that it adds "undefined" in the beginning of every paragraph, and adds random words at the end. Could someone please help us?

We make that the sentence begins with a capital letter and that it ends with a dot.

PD: Adding the snippet it doesn't generate random text, but in the .js file it does.

```js
var buttonElem = document.getElementById("DoAgain");
buttonElem.addEventListener('click', makeNewString);


var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Nullam malesuada ac nulla id interdum Nam volutpat nulla id neque scelerisque ut imperdiet tellus mattis Aliquam a consectetur felis Praesent at eros lorem Nunc id pretium lacus sed porta ex Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Maecenas mollis posuere auctor Aenean ultrices eleifend diam mattis varius tellus convallis sagittis Donec ut lacus vel nulla laoreet mollis Quisque faucibus nunc at nisi ullamcorper facilisis";

var mixedRes=[];

var currentPosition=0;

var newString = "";


function addTag(){
 newString = "<p>" + str + "</p>";
}


function makeNewString() {
    
    str=str.toLocaleLowerCase();
    var res = str.split(" ");
     mixedRes = shuffle(res);
   
    
    for(var i=0; i< mixedRes.length; i++)
    {
      newString += mixedRes[i] + " ";
    }
    
    newString+=makeSentence(6);

        document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = newString;    
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function capitalise(word){
 return (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.slice(1));
}

function makeSentence(slenght){
 var slength=randomNumber(5,10);
   
    var upperCaseLetter = "";
    upperCaseLetter=mixedRes[currentPosition].charAt(0).toUpperCase();

 for (var i=currentPosition+1; i<currentPosition+slength;i++){
  newString+=mixedRes[i]+"";
 }
 
 currentPosition+=slength;
    
    var finalString=upperCaseLetter+newString+".";

   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = finalString;
}

function makeParagraph(){
 newString+="/n";
}

function randomNumber(a,b) {
    return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a));
}
```

```html
<p id="demo0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Nullam malesuada ac nulla id interdum Nam volutpat nulla id neque scelerisque ut imperdiet tellus mattis Aliquam a consectetur felis Praesent at eros lorem Nunc id pretium lacus sed porta ex Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Maecenas mollis posuere auctor Aenean ultrices eleifend diam mattis varius tellus convallis sagittis Donec ut lacus vel nulla laoreet mollis Quisque faucibus nunc at nisi ullamcorper facilisis.</p>

<button class="button1" id="DoAgain"> DO IT AGAIN</button>
```

Comment: I dont see demo1 element but you use : document.getElementById("demo1")

Comment: You have `newString+=makeSentence(6);` but `makeSentence()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code Change This

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = finalString;
```

into

```
document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = finalString;
```

Comment: That fixes the error in the snippet, but it doesn't fix the problem with `undefined` in the random text.

Answer (score 0):

You have `newString+=makeSentence(6);` in your code, but `makeSentence()` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. I guess it's supposed to return `finalString` instead of assigning it to `.innerHTML` of an element that doesn't exist.

```js
var buttonElem = document.getElementById("DoAgain");
buttonElem.addEventListener('click', makeNewString);


var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Nullam malesuada ac nulla id interdum Nam volutpat nulla id neque scelerisque ut imperdiet tellus mattis Aliquam a consectetur felis Praesent at eros lorem Nunc id pretium lacus sed porta ex Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Maecenas mollis posuere auctor Aenean ultrices eleifend diam mattis varius tellus convallis sagittis Donec ut lacus vel nulla laoreet mollis Quisque faucibus nunc at nisi ullamcorper facilisis";

var mixedRes = [];

var currentPosition = 0;

var newString = "";

function addTag() {
  newString = "<p>" + str + "</p>";
}

function makeNewString() {

  str = str.toLocaleLowerCase();
  var res = str.split(" ");
  mixedRes = shuffle(res);
  newString += mixedRes.join(" ") + " ";

  newString += makeSentence(6);

  document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = newString;
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

function capitalise(word) {
  return (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
}

function makeSentence(slenght) {
  var slength = randomNumber(5, 10);

  var upperCaseLetter = "";
  upperCaseLetter = mixedRes[currentPosition].charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  for (var i = currentPosition + 1; i < currentPosition + slength; i++) {
    newString += mixedRes[i] + "";
  }

  currentPosition += slength;

  var finalString = upperCaseLetter + newString + ".";

  return finalString;
}

function makeParagraph() {
  newString += "/n";
}

function randomNumber(a, b) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a) + parseInt(a));
}
```

```html
<p id="demo0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Nullam malesuada ac nulla id interdum Nam volutpat nulla id neque scelerisque ut imperdiet tellus mattis Aliquam a consectetur felis Praesent at eros lorem Nunc id pretium lacus sed porta ex Pellentesque
  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Maecenas mollis posuere auctor Aenean ultrices eleifend diam mattis varius tellus convallis sagittis Donec ut lacus vel nulla laoreet mollis Quisque faucibus nunc at nisi
  ullamcorper facilisis.</p>

<button class="button1" id="DoAgain"> DO IT AGAIN</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! It works, but we have to keep .innerHTML and instead of changing the text now it adds text. That started to happen after return finalString.

Comment: Why did you have `+makeSentence()` if you didn't want to add text?

Comment: The function was adding text to `demo1`, which doesn't exist in the HTML.